# How can Caine, being blind, still play poker?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-4

There is a scene from *John Wick Chapter 4* (2023) where John Wick, Caine, Tracker and Killa
play a poker:

[image]

How can Caine, being blind, still play poker?

Comment: I got spoiled because I didn't know this question was about the John Wick universe and clicked the title in HNQ.

Comment: Its not a particularly important part of the movie @Clockwork

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Realistically, he doesn't

He just takes what he gets and waits for the game to play out.

The game is obviously rigged so John gets Aces & Eights (Dead Man's Hand), Caine gets four nines and Tracker a Royal Flush and Killa **Five** deuces.

Caine never takes any cards or, obviously, looks at them.

From the [screenplay](https://deadline.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/John-Wick-Chapter-4-Read-The-Screenplay.pdf)

> John eyes his cards. The Tracker pulls only the top edge
> back. Caine doesn’t bother to check.
>
> ...
>
> Caine... nods. Passes his hand over his cards. He’ll hold.